# Why mapping onto an object gives me last item only?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Why mapping onto an object gives me last item only? This is the object as shown in console:

0: {Transport: 2}

1: {Implementation: 9}

2: {Management: 3}

When make ngFor give my last item

```
const obj = this.assigned_group;
// refined collection
const result = Object.values(
  obj.reduce((c, v) => {
    c[v] = c[v] || [v, 0];
    c[v][1]++;
    return c;
  }, {})
).map((o) => ({ [o[0]]: o[1] }));

this.assigned_group_delta = result.map((a) => {
  this.x = a;
});
console.log(this.x);

// output give last item only in object
```

Comment: The reason why you use `Array.prototype.map` here. the `Array.prototype.map` will help you map original array data to new array data https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with this method:

```
countItem(item: any) {
  const counts = {};
  const sampleArray = item;
  sampleArray.forEach(function (x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1; });
  return counts;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You're repeatedly overwriting `this.x`

This is why it's value is the last item.

Comment: Thanks for reply, should return a ; ?

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you want to do? it's not clear now

Comment: I want to make *ngFor on result and when make console.log(result) give me                 
  0: {Transport: 2}

1: {Implementation: 9}

2: {Management: 3}                                                        I want to display name and number (Transport: 2) in html